# How do you use ROS with Qt 5.8 or higher?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, camera, ros

I have made a user interface for a robot that requires the `QCamera` class, which is only available for Qt 5.8 or higher, to display the camera of the robot. I want to be able to communicate with the user interface and send it values from C++ code to display using ROS. I have put a lot of time into this interface and would hate to scrap it but every tutorial I am finding on the internet on how to connect ROS to Qt is for an older versions of Qt.

Is it possible to use ROS with Qt 5.8 or ideally Qt 5.9.1 since that is what I have currently installed. Or is there a way to display a camera image in Qt 4.8 without the library multimedia widgets.

If I do have to scrap this whole thing anyone have a software recommendation for some other IDE I can use with ROS, possibly RQt? If it is possible could someone give me a link to a good Qt 5.9.1 or 5.12 tutorial on how to install it with ROS cause I am having a hard time finding it.

Comment: It is unclear what your exact problem is. If I understand correctly, you have Qt 5.9.1 application, and you want to use 3rd party library/framework (Ros) with it, but there is exiting adaptation layer (rqt?) which only supports Qt 4? Are you sure about that, have you tried? Because rqt page at ROS Wiki also mentions Qt 5.3 as minimum requirement for something. Also, rqt seems to be maintained, and Qt 4 is no longer supported (for free), so it'd be odd if maintained software required unmaintained Qt version...

Comment: Also, "some other IDE"? Qt is not an IDE. Are you confusing Qt (framework) and Qt Creator (general purpose IDE with lot of Qt support built in).

Comment: Also, asking for recommendations for external resources is explicitly off topic here, so I would remove that last part of your question. Then clarify what exactly is your problem. SO is geared towards questions about specific problems, not vague "how do I do this complex thing" questions.

Comment: I am looking a for anyway to get around this problem?

Comment: What problem? What error do you get? Which step fails, when you try it?

Comment: on qt version 5.7 or lower there is an option to make a ros program but in 5.8 or higher which is what I need because I am using the multimedia library there is no ros option on the ros website it says you can import a qt project into rqt but the page that is suppose to help you do it is still being developed does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So what happens if you try to use it with newer Qt than 5.7?

Comment: there is no option to make a ros package with the newer qt when I try that is the problem